# Save pandas dataframe to json by column value

Tags: python, json, pandas

I have a dataframe with 10000 rows that look like below:

```
    import numpy as np
df=pd.DataFrame(np.array([['facebook', '15',"women tennis"], ['facebook', '20',"men basketball"], ['facebook', '30','club'],
                          ['apple', "10","vice president"], ['apple', "100",'swimming contest']]),columns=['firm','id','text'])
```

[image]

I'd like to save each firm into a separate JSON file. So the json file for Facebook looks like below, with the file name written as "firm.json" (e.g. facebook.json). The same will be for other firms, such as Apple.

[image]

Sorry, I am still a beginner to Pandas, is there a way to do so effectively?

Comment: if you have a large dataset like 10000 rows, you should try pandas manipulation to avoid for-loops and lambda functions

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do:

```py
json_cols = df.columns.drop('firm').tolist()
json_records = df.groupby('firm')[json_cols].apply(
                          lambda x:x.to_json(orient='records'))
```

Then for 'facebook':

```
facebook_json = json_records['facebook']

'[{"id":"15","text":"women tennis"},
  {"id":"20","text":"men basketball"},
  {"id":"30","text":"club"}]'
```

for 'apple':

```
apple_json = json_records['apple']

'[{"id":"10","text":"vice president"},{"id":"100","text":"swimming contest"}]'
```

Save all at once

```
for col, records in json_records.iteritems():
    with open(f"{col}.json", "w") as file:
        file.write(records)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import json

df = pd.DataFrame(
    np.array([
        ['facebook', '15',"women tennis"],
        ['facebook', '20',"men basketball"],
        ['facebook', '30','club'],
        ['apple', "10","vice president"],
        ['apple', "100",'swimming contest']]
    ), columns=['firm','id','text']
)

firms = set(df.firm)
for firm in firms:
    df_firm = df[df.firm == firm]
    d = []
    for _, r in df_firm.iterrows():
        d.append({'id': r.id, 'Text': str(r.text)})
    with open(f'{firm}.json', 'w') as f:
        json.dump(d, f)
```

I'm sure there's a simpler way, but thats one way.

Comment: Do not use iterrows() unless required. Iterating rows in dataframe is slow.

Comment: As long as runtime is not crucial I do not see any issue using it. OP did not specify any such constraints.

Answer (score 1):

Here's one way to do it:

```
import json
import numpy as np

df=pd.DataFrame(np.array([['facebook', '15',"women tennis"], ['facebook', '20',"men basketball"], ['facebook', '30','club'],
                          ['apple', "10","vice president"], ['apple', "100",'swimming contest']]),columns=['firm','id','text'])

for firm in set(df['firm']):
    f = open(firm + '.json', 'w')
    f.write(json.dumps(list(df[df['firm']==firm][['id', 'text']].T.to_dict().values())))
    f.close()
```

Output:

```
apple.json
[{"id": "10", "text": "vice president"}, {"id": "100", "text": "swimming contest"}]

facebook.json
[{"id": "15", "text": "women tennis"}, {"id": "20", "text": "men basketball"}, {"id": "30", "text": "club"}]
```